# Add 'Min SDK Version' in IntelliJ during project creation

Tags: android, intellij-idea

Anyway, although I like the IntelliJ's way of not adding Min SDK Version into the manifest file (Eclipse adds it by default), I wonder if there is a way to add it during a new project creation?

At the moment I add the SDK limit manually into the manifest file which is ok most of time, but not with the current project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to add it when creating a project, only manually in the AndroidManifest.xml file after the project is created.

Answer (score 1):

change  this code    number  to any thing u want

```
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19"/>
```

like this